# iPython nbconvert and latex: use .eps instead of .png for plots

Tags: ipython

I have an iPython notebook that contains an inline plot (i.e. it contains the command *plot(x,y)*). When I issue the command *ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF --SphinxTransformer.author='Myself' MyNotebook.ipynb* the resulting .PDF file contains the figure, but it has been exported to .PNG, so it doesn't look very good (pixelated). How can I tell **nbconvert** to export all plots/figures to .EPS instead?

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all the notebook is not responsible for creating plots, but *matplotlib* and this allows to render your plots as eps, pdf, svg, etc. in great quality to be included in publications.

I agree that the default inline plot format, i.e. `png` is not optimal to be used for publications due to several reasons. As given in the github issue you posted in your answer, the inline backend can be configured to use `svg` instead of `png` by calling

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
```

in a code cell.
With this, the **newly created** plots will be vectorial, (as Matt said, already rendered pngs will not be converted!). These svgs are embedded in the notebook (svgs can be rendered by modern browsers) and are subsequently converted to pdfs by nbconvert. These pdfs fulfil the requirements of publication ready plots. However, be aware that the svgs can be really huge (compared with pngs) and may slow down the notebook handling significantly.

Your initial question was about `eps` graphics. As said above, matplotlib can render eps, hence, you can always do something like `savefig('plot1.eps')` to create the desired figures. That's actually the way I create my publication figures (png in notebook, eps in paper). 
Let's assume we would get IPython to generate eps files (embedded but not renderable in the browser). The `tex` file generated by *nbconvert* is designed to work with *pdflatex*. If fed with eps files *pdflatex* would convert these to pdf to be included in the final document. So basically it does the same as *nbconvert* currently does with the svgs. Thus, there is no benefit.

Finally, I want to point out that, even though the tex files generated by nbconvert look great (especially the ones created using the master branch), IMHO there is no way to use these files without touching (e.g. adding captions, scaling images, ...). Therefore, you could always include the eps files at this step into your papers.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help. I have tried using the = 'svg' option in the iPython notebook, but when I try running nbconvert i get a long error message, where the gist of it is: "TypeError: Inkscape svg to png conversion failed". So nbconvert still wants to convert the plot to .PNG? And sorry about not being very specific about the final format (i.e. not necesarrily .EPS): I just wanted to use iPython to write up an entire assignment in (with good plots)

Comment: Have you installed inkscape? The error message is simply wrong :) > the conversion is svg2pdf.

Comment: Aaah, no, I installed inkscape and now it works. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NBconvert does **not** run your code. So if you haven't plotted with SVG matplotlib backend it is not possible.
If you did so, then you need to write a nbconvert preprocessor that does svg-> eps and extend the relevant template to know how to embed EPS.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this is a missing feature in nbconvert. There is not currently a way to get publication quality plots in your final PDF: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3603

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/3693

Comment: Actually, I disagree here, please see my answer why.